# How to delay asset loading in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: networking, google-chrome-devtools

Can I add a resource delay in the Google Chrome browser using the Chrome developer tools?

The reason why I want to do this, I need to find errors that are associated with slow loading from some resources.

I tried installing a slow internet or latency. But this affects the download speed from all resources, and I need only from some.
Thanks!

Comment: See how to [Emulate slow network connections](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#throttling) in the official documentation.

Comment: While we're at it, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).